# Selenium Python code

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

This is my very first time trying to scrape data from a website using Selenium. Fortunately I have got Selenium and Chrome to coordinate and the desired website opens.Once it opens up, I want to tell Python to click '`SEARCH`' leaving the empty box blank (next to contains) and then tell Python to export the results ' and save the `xlsx` file as `result_file`. I do not know why the snippet is blowing up. Please provide your kind assistance.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Python27\Scripts\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://etrakit.friscotexas.gov/Search/permit.aspx")

number_option = driver.find_element_by_id("cplMain_btnSearch")
number_option.click()

search_button = driver.find_element_by_id("cplMain_btnExportToExcel")
search_button.click()

result_file = open("result_file.xlsx", "w")

driver.close()
result_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source of that page, the ID of the search button is "cplMain_btnSearch" not "SEARCH". And the Export button is "cplMain_btnExportToExcel".

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I have updated my original post with the code. The search works great but the Export to Excel still does not download the file.

Comment: You might need to put in a wait while the Ajax script fetches the results and shows the export button.

Answer (score 0):

To expand the answer of Daniel Roseman, you also need to specify the download location

```
options.add_argument("download.default_directory=C:/Python27")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

The file will then be stored in your `python27` directory with the name `RadGridExport.csv`.

Comment: Thanks Maximilian, I needed that.